# Induced subgraphs of cycles

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph of order $5$ such that the induced subgraph formed by removing any $2$ vertices in $G$ is not isomorphic to the nullgraph or $C_3.$ It seems clear that $G = C_5.$ Could someone advise me how to prove this assertion? Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: How is $C_n$ defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may already know the result that for a $6$-vertex graph, this is impossible: in any $6$-vertex graph $G$, there is either a $3$-vertex empty subgraph, or a $3$-vertex $C_3$ subgraph. (Usually we say $K_3$ - the $3$-vertex clique - rather than $C_3$ - the $3$-vertex cycle, even though they're the same, because the most common generalization of this result is to larger cliques and not to larger cycles.)

If not, let me summarize the proof. You pick a vertex $v$, and consider two cases:

- There are three vertices $w_1,w_2,w_3$ all adjacent to $v$. Then having any edge $w_iw_j$ creates a $K_3$ induced by $\{v,w_i,w_j\}$, and having no such edge creates an empty subgraph induced by $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$.
- There are three vertices $w_1,w_2,w_3$ all *not* adjacent to $v$. Then missing any edge $w_iw_j$ creates an empty subgraph induced by $\{v, w_i, w_j\}$, and having all three such edges creates $K_3$ induced by $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$.

(One of these cases must happen by the pigeonhole principle, because out of $5$ other vertices either three are neighbors of $v$ or else three are non-neighbors of $v$.)

Now for a hint as to how to proceed in your case: consider this proof carefully, and think about cases where it would also work for a $5$-vertex graph. We know it doesn't work for *all* $5$-vertex graphs, because it doesn't work for $C_5$. But we can try to show that the proof still works *unless* the graph has some specific property, and then try to show that this property implies that the graph is $C_5$.

(This is a really common technique throughout math in general.)

Comment: Here is my proof:
Given any vertex $v$ in $G$ of order $5,$ either $v$ is adjacent to $2$ vertices or $v$ is not adjacent to $3$ vertices.

Suppose there exists $v$ that is not adjacent to $3$ vertices $x_1,x_2,x_3.$  Since the subgraph induced by $\{v,x_i,x_j\}$ $(i,j=1,2,3)$ is not the null graph, there must be an edge between $x_i$ and $x_j.$ This will create a $3$-vertex cycle $C_3$ subgraph.  Hence, $v$ must be adjacent to $2$ vertices. In particular, if $v$ is adjacent to more than $2$ vertices, $C_3$ subgraph will be induced. It follows that $\text{deg} (v)=2$ and $G= C_5.$

Comment: Seems good. (Some things that you may or may not want to elaborate on, depending on how obvious you think they are: the case where $v$ is adjacent to more than $2$ vertices, which is a mirror of the non-adjacent case. Going from having $\deg(v)=2$ for all $v$ to $G=C_5$.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Suppose $\text{deg}(a) =2$ for all $a.$ Then $a$ is adjacent to $b,c$. Since no $C_3$ subgraph is induced, $b$ is not adjacent to $c.$ Now, the $4$th vertex $d$ must be adjacent to $b(\text{or} \ c)$. It is clear that the $5$th vertex $e$ must be adjacent to $c$  and $d.$ This gives us $C_5.$

Comment: Yes, that works. (Actually, $C_5$ is the only $2$-regular graph on $5$ vertices even without the $C_3$-free condition, but we don't need to prove that.)